# Javascript - generate array pair

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently studying Javascript and working on a challenge and running into a snag. the challenge requires creating a function that accepts an integer and generates an array containing the pairs of integers [a, b]. The pairs should be sorted by increasing values of a then increasing values of b.

generatePairs(1) // returns [ [0, 0], [0, 1], [1,1]]

My code is below:

```
    function generatePairs(num){
  var arr = [[],[]];
  for(let i = 0; i <=num; i++){
    arr.unshift([i])
    console.log(arr);

    for(j=0; j<num; j++){

      arr.unshift(arr[[i],[j]]);
      console.log(arr);
    }

  }
  return arr;
}
```

and this is my result-

```
[ [ 0 ], [], [] ]
[ [ 0 ], [ 0 ], [], [] ]
[ [ 1 ], [ 0 ], [ 0 ], [], [] ]
[ [ 1 ], [ 1 ], [ 0 ], [ 0 ], [], [] ]
=> [ [ 1 ], [ 1 ], [ 0 ], [ 0 ], [], [] ]
```

I'm stumped as to what is wrong here. Any suggestions/corrections would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: How large can `num` be? We're returning permutations of all pairs from 0..n? What's the output for, say, 3? I'm a bit unclear on the goal.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the actual problem statement? What are "the pairs of integers [a, b]"? Why is there no `[1, 0]` in the result?

Comment: @ggorlen num is as large as provided in the function call. in this example, it is 1 generatePairs(1).

Comment: @ASDFGerte the [a,b] is an example of how it should be paired. This function is only taking integers.

Comment: @ggorlen I see what you mean. the largest number expected in the challenge is 3 to as to not run into performance issues

below is the max number provided in the challenge.
generatePairs(3) // [ [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3] ]
.

Comment: Just hardcode the results for 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with two nested for loops like this:

```js
function generatePairs(num){
  let v = []
  
  for (let i=0; i <= num; i++) {
    for (let j=i; j <= num; j++) {
        v.push([i, j])
    }
  }
  
  return v
}

console.log(generatePairs(3))
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought i was on the right track but, I seemed to have gotten in my head and over-complicated my process. I guess I need to go back to the basics.

Comment: No problem! If this helped you please consider accepting the answer